# Python finding Prime Numbers between any two numbers

Tags: python, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I'm trying to find prime numbers between any two random numbers.

Firstly, I have written the code like:

```
m,n = map(int, raw_input().split())
for i in range(m, n+1):
    for j in range(2, i):
        if i%j == 0:
            break
    else:
        print i,
```

Now for test case suppose I enter 2, 30 then it prints

2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29

Now analyzing, we don't need to loop till "i" in second loop rather we can do same by looping till i/2, then I changed the code as:

```
m,n = map(int, raw_input().split())
for i in range(m, n+1):
    for j in range(2, int(i/2)+1):
        if i%j == 0:
            break
    else:
        print i,
```

Then the result is same as above while we looped till i/2 in second loop.

Now, I'm trying to use the Sieve of Eratosthenes method to print the prime numbers and I used the code as:

```
m,n = map(int, raw_input().split())
for i in range(m, n+1):
    sqrt_num = int(n**(0.5))
    for j in range(2, sqrt_num+1):
        if i%j == 0:
            break
    else:
        print i,
```

but it prints

7 11 13 17 19 23 29

for the same input.

Please help me to understand what I am doing wrong. And how I can accomplish the same using this method.

Comment: Have you tested your code on a number range like [24..28]?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't print any number because there is no prime in [24..28].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your inner loop used to loop up until `i-1` or `i/2`.  This inner loop was short when `i` was small, and longer when `i` got larger.

Now, your inner loop goes up to `sqrt_num`, which is a constant computed from `n`.  Difference in behavior.

Consider `i = 3`, the inner loop runs from `j = 2` to `j = 5`, and will find a case where `i%j == 0` ... specifically, when `j == 3`.

---

To be clear: the problem is "`sqrt_num`, which is a constant".  Change it to the square root of the outer index, `i`.

```
    sqrt_num = int(i**(0.5))
```

Comment: Yes, you are right but how can I make to work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

start = int(input('enter starting point of interval:'))

end = int(input('enter ending point of interval:'))

teap=[]

for i in range (start,end):

```
if i>1:
    for j in range(2,i):
        if i%j==0:
            break
    else:
        teap.append(i)
```

chunk_size = 10

chunked_list = [teap[i:i+chunk_size] for i in range(0, len(teap), chunk_size)]

print(chunked_list)